# Hive/Athena : Ignore fields while creating table

Tags: json, hiveql, amazon-athena

I have to load data in json format into hive.Below is the sample data which is in JSON format.I need to create a table 'emp' in the 'test' database with empno, name, salary and updated columns.Please advice on how to write a create table statement that accepts data from these columns.

{"schema": "test", "table": "emp", "type": "WriteRowsEvent", "row": {"values": {"empno": 20, "name": "Ram", "salary": 20000.0, "updated": "2020-05-21T21:47:01"}}}{"schema": "test", "table": "emp", "type": "WriteRowsEvent", "row": {"values": {"empno": 30, "name": "Dev", "salary": 30000.0, "updated": "2020-05-21T21:47:26"}}}

Comment: The community expects you to tell what you have done. We don't accept outsourced work.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your JSON file format below:

```
{"schema": "test", "table": "emp", "type": "WriteRowsEvent", "row": {"values": {"empno": 20, "name": "Ram", "salary": 20000.0, "updated": "2020-05-21T21:47:01"}}}
```

I was able to generate the table statement using this generator: https://www.hivetablegenerator.com/

HiveQL create table statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`mytable` (
    `schema` STRING,
    `table` STRING,
    `type` STRING,
    `row` STRUCT<
    `values`:STRUCT<
    `empno`:INT,
`name`:STRING,
`salary`:DOUBLE,
`updated`:STRING>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
     'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION
     's3://awsexamplebucket1-logs/AWSLogs/'
```